# preg_replace all non-digit characters and except all numbers wth 10 digits

Tags: php

I want to check if the user's input in the server side is correct . If the user enters a numbers and characters like: 1234567891 IS my REFER NUMBER 12 an 1234567899 IS REFER 2.

i will need to allow only Nunbers with 10 Digits sparated by comma, all others unwanted characters and spaces should removed the output: 1234567891,1234567899 should be stored as a variable

i have already used pregmatch
i have this code but it only remove spaces and charactres

```
$var= preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $var);
```

Comment: Something like this might help you get started: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/q4L

Comment: @RobbieAverill wouldn't `preg_match_all` be better so both numbers get returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`, with the pattern `\b[0-9]{10}\b`:

```
$input = "1234567891 IS my REFER NUMBER 12 an 1234567899 IS REFER 2 and 123456789 and 12345678901";
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{10}\b/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => 1234567891
    [1] => 1234567899
)
```

Note that my sample input had both 10 digit and non 10 digit numbers present, and only the former were present in the output.

**Edit:**

If you wanted all of the matching array numbers in a single string, you could try using `join`, e.g.

```
$output = join('\n', $matches[0]);
echo $output;

1234567891
1234567899
```

Comment: thanx but  it only returne results as array how to extract those results  to a $?

Comment: @unlockit I don't know exactly what output you want, but `join` is one option.